# Are there technical documents about microprocessor design by Jim Keller?

Tags: microprocessor, chip-design

[Jim Keller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Keller_(engineer)) has worked leading various chip design projects at Intel, AMD, Apple and Tesla among other companies.

Does anybody know of any technical documents about microprocessor design written by him? I couldn’t find anything in IEEE Xplore and on the web all I could find were nontechnical interviews.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If he wrote a book you should be able to find easily. Any technical documents he wrote might be "company confidential" meaning his (former) employers own those documents and they're not sharing them. What are you hoping to find in Jim Keller's legacy that you cannot find elsewhere?

Comment: Hi @Bimpelrekkie: I searched at my local library for a book written by him as well and couldn't find anything, I thought it is less likely to find a book than a single article (to write a book takes more time and effort). What I am hoping to find is to know if he has written some "design principles" of microprocessor design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try searching for James B. Keller or JB Keller or J. Keller. I think you'll find a number of publications which list him as an author. For example, US 8775757, US 8392658 patents, some more patents listed [here](https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/2108818027_James_B_Keller)

Also "Measuring VAX 8800 performance with a histogram hardware monitor", "Internal architecture of Alpha 21164 microprocessor", "A 600 MHz superscalar RISC microprocessor with out-of-order execution" IEEE

Interestingly, perhaps, he's apparently married to the sister of (in)famous Canadian clinical psychologist and author [Jordan Peterson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_Peterson).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sphero! I didn't think about searching for patents but in hindsight is really obvious :p Also, those papers are quite interesting but relatively old, from his time at DEC. do you know any more recent papers?

Comment: No, probably his later employers did not encourage unnecessary publishing.